# Equivalencias de codigo visual Basic a C#

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de pasarme y pasar una solución de `visual basic` a `c#`, he tenido problemas en el aprendizaje de la sintaxis, ahorita me encuentro detenido con estas lineas:

Conversión #1

```
Dim aoIniFile As axdLibrary.IniFileName = New IniFileName(acdataDirectory & "\cnxapp.ini")
```

Conversión #2

```
Private WithEvents aoCnx As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Settings.mCnxSrv.ToString)
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: utilizar los materiales para ejecutar código por favor por que no es comprensible..ver ayuda para [escritura para Markdown](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: ¿Cómo falla lo que has hecho? ¿Qué error recibes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
axdLibrary.IniFileName aoIniFile  = new axdLibrary.IniFileName(acdataDirectory + "\\cnxapp.ini");
```

1.- "*WithEvents*" no existe como tal en C#. Su "equivalente", es más bien, una aproximación similar / replica. Ver código más abajo.

2.- La sentencia "*My.Settings.mCnxSrv.ToString*" hace referencia a un objeto y su llamada particular en VB. Su equivalente sería el objeto 'Settings'.

```
System.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Settings.mCnxSrv.ToString());
conn.StateChange += new EventHandler(Metodo_CambioDeEstado);

private void Metodo_CambioDeEstado (object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

**Artículos MSDN:**

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6e26ffc7-1bf2-4909-a376-edf8681a49fd/withevents-c-workaround?forum=csharpgeneral
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cba07eb4-6c98-4e58-9d84-9486fa885cc2/c-equivalent-to-vb-withevents?forum=csharpgeneral

Answer (score 0):

## 1

```
axdLibrary.IniFileName aoIniFile = new IniFileName(acdataDirectory + "\\cnxapp.ini");
```

## 2

```
private SqlClient.SqlConnection aoCnx = new SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Settings.mCnxSrv.ToString);
```

> Puedes utilizar un conversor online como: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Gracias, lo probare en este momento.

Comment: Esas dos me funcionaron al 100%, ahora tengo problemas con esta intruccion  ; this.Item("mCnxSifco") = acCnxApp.Trim.Replace("qmasuser", acUserId);, necesito guardar el setting del proyecto, pero voy siguiendo tus consejos, nada  mas que es algo lento el APRENDISAJE